# NestJS CLI outputs garbage

Tags: command-line-interface, nestjs

I have used NestJS quite a bit and also it's CLI, but when I wanted to use it now, it started outputting garbage, with every command I tried:

```
    nest
    nest info
    nest new
    npm run start:dev
```

This started happening today. I generated a new project, and from then every NestJS CLI command started looking like this:
(i have tried reinstalling the CLI and rebooting the computer, also angular and ionic CLIs work just fine)
[image: NestJS CLI output]

Comment: tip: every time you face an issue with `@nestjs/*` go to their repo first on the issues tab (and report it there if needed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue due to an update to `colors.js` that `cli-table3` depends on that the Nest CLI depends on. There's [already a PR to fix it](https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/pull/1478) and it should be fixed within a day. [More discussion on GitHub here](https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/issues/1480)

---

If you're still running into this, make sure you're using `@nestjs/cli@8.1.8` or higher.

Comment: Thanks @Jay McDoniel!
Temporarily I have just installed colors v1.4.0 to my global @nest/cli node_modules and also in local project and it works fine. Waiting for the next release.

Comment: nestjs/cli 8.1.8 has just fixed that.